# How do you call a method from within a Collector in Java 8 Streaming?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a bit of code that is working functionally as I want it to:

```
private Map<Florist, EnumSet<Flower>> localMethod(List<FlowerSellers> branchList) {
    Map<Florist, EnumSet<Flower>> availableFlowers = new EnumMap<>(Florist.class);

    branchList.stream()
              .filter(f -> f instanceof FlorestFranchised)
              .forEach(f -> availableFlowers.put(
                      FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey(f.id()), 
                      ((FlorestFranchised) f).getFlowers()));

    return availableFlowers;
}
```

For sake of argument the helper class method is:

```
public static Florist FlorestTypeForKey(String id) {
    return FLOREST_MAP.get(id);
}
```

I would like to do this with a collector instead so I wanted to do this ...

```
return branchList.stream()
                 .filter(p -> p instanceof FlorestFranchised)
                 .map(p -> (FlorestFranchised) p)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                         FlorestFranchised::getId,  
                         FlorestFranchised::getFlowers));
```

But obviously this fails because it is not doing the helper class lookup and so rather than returning a map of <Florest, Flowers> it is returning <String, Flowers>

This fails though :

```
return branchList.stream()
                 .filter(p -> p instanceof FlorestFranchised)
                 .map(p -> (FlorestFranchised) p)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                         FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey(FlorestFranchised::getId),
                         FlorestFranchised::getFlowers));
```

Can anyone tell me how I should call the lookup methods `(FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey)` in the collector? Is it possible?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Method names should be written in camelCase. So `FlorestTypeForKey` should be `florestTypeForKey`.

Comment: Just take some time and not, what was already working for you simple translation for `f -> availableFlowers.put(FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey(f.id())`. Notice the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap` requires two functions creating a key and value respectively from the value passed into the `collect` method. Therefore you can do this:

```
return branchList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p instanceof FlorestFranchised)
    .map(p -> (FlorestFranchised) p)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey(p.getId()),   // key
        p -> p.getFlowers()                                     // value
));
```

The last lambda expression can be replaced with `FlorestFranchised::getFlowers`.

Answer (score 2):

You can map first as `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` pair then use `Collectors.toMap`

```
return branchList
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> p instanceof FlorestFranchised )
    .map(p -> (FlorestFranchised) p )
    .map(p -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                 FlorestHelperClass.florestTypeForKey(p.getId()), p.getFlowers()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: If you're going to take the time to create an Entry then you may as well use a method reference instead of a lambda.  (e.g. `Entry::getKey`).  It's more efficient.